# Java Algorithms ResizingStringArrayQueue Resize Method Problems

Tags: java, algorithm, implementation

So I'm in the process of learning how to use algorithms and I'm using the Algorithms Book By Robert Sedgewick to learn how to do this and the question is Exercise 1.3.14 (I would recommend highly if you are wanting to learn this stuff.) Anyway, I'm trying to implement my own resizing algorithm for my ResizingStringArrayQueue and I'm really struggling to get my implementation to work. But before I delve further into this, I would like to ask politely that I am NOT looking for a full solution to my resizing array (I'm trying to learn so need to do this by myself.) However if someone would be able to explain to me why my resizing method is failing to copy itself into a new larger array any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to emphasise here that I'm focusing on the enque method, and am not working on the deque at this stage so please, no solution to how the deque works, thanks!

So here goes...

This is my implementation for the ResizingStringArrayQueue:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ResizingArrayQueueOfStrings implements Iterable<String> {

private String[] a = new String[1]; 
private int n; 
private int head;
private int tail; 

public boolean isEmpty() { return n==0; } 
public int size() {return n; }


public void aPrint() { // temporary method for testing needs deleting
    System.out.println("Contents of array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(a[i]+ " ");
    } 
}   

private void resize(int max) {  
    String[] temp = new String[max];
    for (int i = head; i < tail; i++) {
        temp[i] = a[i]; 
        a = temp;
    }
}

public void enque(String item) { // something is in the wrong order here

    if (tail == a.length) {
        System.out.println("Capacity Doubled");
        resize(2*a.length);
    }
    n++;
    a[tail++] = item;
}

public String deque() {
    if (head == tail/2) {
        resize(n);
        head = 0;
        tail = n;
    }

    n--;
    String item = a[head];
    a[head++] = null; // loitering
    return item;
}

public Iterator<String> iterator(){
    return new ResizingArrayQueueIterator();
}

private class ResizingArrayQueueIterator implements Iterator<String>{

    private int i = head;


    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {

        return i < tail; 
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return a[i++];
    }

}
```

}

And this is a copy of my Main():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // EXERCISE 1.3.14
    System.out.println("EXERCISE 1.3.14 ");
    System.out.println();
    ResizingArrayQueueOfStrings queueOfStrings = new ResizingArrayQueueOfStrings();
    queueOfStrings.enque("a");
    queueOfStrings.enque("b");
    queueOfStrings.enque("c");
    queueOfStrings.enque("d");
    queueOfStrings.enque("e");

    System.out.println();       

    for (String string : queueOfStrings) {
        System.out.println(string);         
    }

    System.out.println();       
    queueOfStrings.aPrint();

}
```

If you comment out the "enques" for c, d and e the code does what it should if you run it, I  get a full queue [a,b]. However, when I get to c, my queue becomes [a,null,c, null] when it should be [a,b,c,null] for some reason it fails to copy the b. So I think the problem lies in the order I'm doing things and its somewhere most likely in the resizing method. I've spent a long time looking at this now and I'm getting to the stage where a second set of eyes would be really helpful. Thank you for your time and patience in advance, I look forward to hearing from you!

Comment: As I see it, tail can never equal a.length because the elements of the array go from 0 to a.lenght - 1.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) The queue does resize if you run the code in the way I expect it should, that's not the problem, the problem is that the array isn't copying correctly. When I enque "b" my String[] is full and looks like [a,b] so when I enqueue "c", it should resize to [a,b,null,null] and then put in c to make [a,b,c,null] but for some reason I'm getting [a,null,b,null]. Something is going wrong with the copying.

Answer (score 0):

In resize, move the statement a = temp out of the for loop.